# Intellij: How do I display Java signature on one line?

Tags: java, methods, intellij-idea, refactoring

The previous developer of some code I'm working on put all the return parameters and access modifiers on the line above the method name and throws below it, yielding stuff like

```
protected boolean
someMethodName(SomeType somename)
        throws Throwable
{
}
```

I can't get used to this; my brain interprets line breaks as breaks in context.  Is there an Intellij command that refactors these into or displays these on a single line?

Comment: What happens when you tell it to reformat the code now?  you can quickly delete the line breaks and use the reformatting to do the rest.

Comment: Doesn't `Ctrl + Alt + L` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help pointing in the right direction, I determined that

Code -> Reformat Code... didn't initially work,

but File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Keep when reformatting -> (Uncheck) Line breaks and *then* a code reformat solved the problem.